# In-wall Cat5e cable pinging 1,3,5,7 when tested — what is on the other end?

Tags: networking, ethernet

I bought a house with cat5e wiring for phone lines to each bedroom. I upgraded each outlet and source at the network box to rj45.

After proper crimping and accounting for all of the outlets on the architect plans, I have one **extra** cat5e cable. **When I apply a cable tester to it it lights up 1,3,5,7** — so it’s clearly connected to something on the other end. But that something is only using these wires (I suppose?)

**What could be on the other end?** I’d like to track down the wire and potentially use it if in a good place.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you aware you can buy cheap signal tracers that can help you with this?  Not a recommendation per-se but something like https://www.amazon.com/Electrical-Generator-Continuity-Automotive-Telephone/dp/B093JQJTP3 or https://www.aliexpress.com/item/4000190732601.html

Comment: I was not actually — thanks for the suggestion. Would love to avoid crawling under the house as the area where the campers go in is hard to access. List wondering if there is an obvious wiring use case that uses only some of the pairs